# How do I make a code that repeats without while-loop?

Tags: python

I'm trying to repeat a code that asks the user for a name, and thereafter asks for a new name. If the user writes a number, the program should ask for a new name. If the user types 'quit' the program should print how many names the user has entered.

So far I've solved it with a while-loop, but would like to do it WITHOUT using a while-loop and still keep prompting the user for new names.

```
participants=[]
count=0

while True:
    user_name=input("Course participant name: ")
    if user_name == "quit":
        print("Number of participants: ", count)
    elif user_name.isdigit():
        continue
    elif user_name.isalpha():
        participants.append(user_name)
        count+=1
    else:
        print("Invalid input")
        break
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is using `for-loop` allowed?

Comment: Yes for-loops are allowed

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why would you want to avoid `while`?

Answer (score 3):

You could use recursion:

```
def ask(participants):
    user_name = input("Course participant name: ")
    if user_name == "quit":
        print("Number of participants: ", len(participants))
    elif user_name.isdigit():
        ask(participants)
    elif user_name.isalpha():
        participants.append(user_name)
        ask(participants)
    else:
        print("Invalid input")
        return
```

Instead of looping, you go deeper and deeper into the call stack. No need to track `count` separately because it is already encoded in the length of `participants`.

Comment: True, see e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/what-is-the-maximum-recursion-depth-in-python-and-how-to-increase-it Given that a user has to press keys for each level it will probably be fine but for practical purposes I would go with the original while-loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for solution using `for` loop then you can do as follow:

```
participants=[]
count=0
from itertools import cycle
for i in cycle(range(0, 1)):
    user_name=input("Course participant name: ")
    if user_name == "quit":
        print("Number of participants: ", count)
    elif user_name.isdigit():
        continue
    elif user_name.isalpha():
         participants.append(user_name)
         count+=1
    else:
         print("Invalid input")
         break
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly tricky way to do it, by using the `participants` list itself and providing an initial element (to start the loop), which will be deleted in the end. The loop will keep going as long as there is a name being inputted, because the `participants` list grows at every iteration.

```
participants=["Start"] # insert initial element, to start the loop
count=0

for i in participants:
    user_name=input("Course participant name: ")
    if user_name == "quit":
        print("Number of participants: ", count)
    elif user_name.isdigit():
        continue
    elif user_name.isalpha():
        participants.append(user_name)
        count+=1
    else:
        print("Invalid input")
        break

del participants[0] # remove initial element
```